# How to check whether a variable is defined in a specific format?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have a template variable test.

```
test = {
    key1: "String",
    key2: {
        key1: Int,
        key2: ["Array","of","Strings"]
    },
    key3: [0,1,2...],   // Array of Integers
    key4: true          // Boolean value 
}
```

Now I want to check if a variable has the same exact "format" of this template, meaning it needs to have 4 keys, one key has to be a String, 
one key has to be an Object that contains 2 keys (Int and Array of Strings), one key has to be an array of integers and one key that has to have a boolean value.

For example, this variable is not in the format of the `test` template variable.

```
example = {
    key1: "String",
    key2: "String",
    key3: "String"
}
```

Is there a way to compare the structure of a variable to another variable to make sure that it is in the right format, which can be used like for example, sending AJAX calls to the server without an issue with the format?

**Note**: The template variable is just an example, it can have any kind of format with any number of nested objects within.

Comment: Are you using `node` as a backend ?

Comment: I am using Javascript (VueJS) in the frontend and PHP as a backend (Laravel).

Comment: maybe json-schema?

Comment: _for example, sending AJAX calls to the server without an issue with the format_ - That sounds like the error checking should be done at the server, not by the client side. That is easy enough if the `test` variable is a known format. Would `key1` always be a `String` and `key2->key1` always be an `int`?

Comment: The `test` template format is constant, so `key1` will always be a string. Perhaps the name of the key might not be 'key1' but the gist is that there has to be 4 keys in the object, whose values are `String, Object (2 keys: Int, Array), Array, Boolean`. I would be checking the format at the backend as well, but it would better if I also was able to define a format at the frontend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a comparison function on just the properties and call that and check the property type match also.

Per comment I added recursion into deeper levels.

You are also going to have to check if an object is an array.  I will leave this `Array.isArray(value)` up to you to put it in the right place.

```js
let basething = {
  key1: "String",
  key2: {
    key1a: 4,
    key2arr: ["Array", "of", "Strings"]
  },
  key3arr: [0, 1, 2], // Array of Integers
  key4: true // Boolean value 
};

let test = {
  key1: "String",
  key2: {
    key1a: 98,
    key2arr: ["Array", "of", "Strings", "not exact"]
  },
  key3arr: [0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 123], // Array of Integers
  key4: true // Boolean value 
};

let example = {
  key1: "String",
  key2: "String",
  key3: "String"
}

function compareProperty(object1, object2) {
  let sameStruct = true;
  for (let p in object1) {
    console.log(p,typeof object1[p]);
    // compare property
    if (!object2.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
      sameStruct = false;
    } else {
      if (object2.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
        if (typeof object1[p] == "object" && typeof object2[p] == "object") {
          sameStruct = sameStruct && compareProperty(object1[p], object2[p]);
        } else {

          // compare type of property
          sameStruct = sameStruct && (typeof object2[p] === typeof object1[p]);
        }
      } else {
        sameStruct = false;
      }
    }
  }
  return sameStruct;
}

let isSame = compareProperty(basething, example);
let isSame2 = compareProperty(basething, test);
console.log(isSame, isSame2);
```

Comment: This doesn't check for the datatypes of the values, though. So it will return true even if the value of the key is a String/Int/Boolean etc. instead of an Array of Strings.

Comment: I added that with an edit, comparing the base types - if the arrays differ in length and that is important, you could also add a check for that.  This is probably not full proof for types that return `typeof` of object.  I would also add that this answer addresses the original question without regard for updates and/or comments.

Comment: This function compares only 1 level nesting of the object, if the value of the key in the innermost nested section turns out to be another object, it returns true nonetheless. Would we need recursion in that case? Is there no easier alternative? The example I gave is just a generalization of what a template could be, would be better if there is a common solution that checks for any kind of object structure within the variable.

Comment: I added the recursion, but as noted "object" gets more complicated, I highlighted the need for array, will leave the rest to you.

Answer (score 2):

You can create array of function each taking one parameter and return `true` or `false` for each of given conditions. Use `every()` on `Object.values` of given object and check whether the any of the function returns true for that value.

```js
const test = {
    key1: "String",
    key2: {
        key1: 55,
        key2: ["Array","of","Strings"]
    },
    key3: [0,1,2],   // Array of Integers
    key4: true          // Boolean value 
}
let cons = [
  x => x.constructor === String,
  x => x.constructor === Array && x.every(a => typeof a === "number"),
  x => x.constructor === Boolean,
  x => {
    if(x.constructor === Object){
      let funs = [
          (x) => x.constructor === Number,
          (x) => x.every(x => x.constructor === String)
      ]
      return testFormat(x,funs)
    }
  }
]



function testFormat(obj, funs){
  let vals = Object.values(obj);
  return vals.length === funs.length && vals.every(x => funs.some(f => f(x)));
}

console.log(testFormat(test, cons))
```

Comment: I tried this code but it seems contrived. It gives an error when I change the data type of any key value, because the code assumes it's an object and does not recognize the `every()`.

Comment: @Tribunal Can you please tell the error. And the change you made to the input. Also check the code again I have updated it a little.

Comment: `TypeError: x.every is not a function`. I changed the datatype of key3 from array of objects to a string, int, boolean etc.

Comment: @Tribunal Please edit my snippet to show the problem. It works fine for me.

Comment: I tested it before you edited the solution. The edited solution does not give errors but  it returns `true` when I change the type of `key3` from `Array` to `String`. Moreover, this is hard-coding the function to check the format of one template, is there a better alternative to have a generalized function that checks the structure of a variable?

Comment: @Tribunal There can be but you first need to try out something yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think https://validatejs.org/ can help you.

`Sometimes it's nice to be able validate field differently depending on the input itself. validate.js allows the validators object and validator options to be a function that should return the constraints/options:`

```
var constraints = {
  username: {
    presence: true,
    exclusion: {
      within: ["nicklas"],
      message: "'%{value}' is not allowed"
    }
  },
  password: {
    presence: true,
    length: {
      minimum: 6,
      message: "must be at least 6 characters"
    }
  }
};

validate({password: "bad"}, constraints);
// => {
//   "username": ["Username can't be blank"],
//   "password": ["Password must be at least 6 characters"]
// }
```

https://validatejs.org/

Comment: Is there a way to do this with vanilla Javascript?

Comment: Yes, but you should create class with `set` and `get` method